# How to keep, but not track a file on GitHub?

Tags: git, github

I have a shared initialization script with user-specific contents I want to share with my team as a template but not have everyone keep updating with their say, own email addresses.

```
  echo "myname" > testfile
  git add testfile
  git commit -m "Add a user-specific file"
  git push push origin master

  echo "testfile" >> .gitignore
  git add .gitignore
  git commit -m "Ignore user-specific file"

  git rm --cached testfile
  # Showing that testfile is staged as deleted!
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a quite similar issue where, I have some "easy build" shell scripts which I want to provide in the tree, and which I expect that people might change but I don't want them to commit the changes when they work.

The way I resolved this in my project is to use `git update-index --assume-unchanged` to protect the build scripts (when appropriate).

I created two bash scripts, `git_assume_build_scripts_unchanged.sh` and `git_undo_assume_build_scripts_unchanged.sh` in the root of the repository, they look like this:

#### git_assume_build_scripts_unchanged.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

# Cause git to assume that all build scripts are unchanged, so that you can use "git add ." syntax to commit
# without committing local changes to the build scripts

git update-index --assume-unchanged *build*.sh
git update-index --assume-unchanged Toolchain-*.cmake
git update-index --assume-unchanged set_*_env_vars.sh
```

#### git_undo_assume_build_scripts_unchanged.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

# Cause git to assume that all build scripts are unchanged, so that you can use "git add ." syntax to commit
# without committing local changes to the build scripts

git update-index --no-assume-unchanged *build*.sh
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged Toolchain-*.cmake
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged set_*_env_vars.sh
```

The idea is that if someone needs to modify the build script for their local machine, or modify the cmake Toolchain files, or similar, they run the first script. `git update-index --assume-unchanged` causes git to mark the files, so that if they are changed in the index, even though they are tracked, those changes will not be detected by git and will not be staged when you use `git add .` or similar.

If someone needs to undo the change, they can use the `undo` script.

Answer (score 0):

what you are probably looking for is this:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>
```

And then, when you want the opposite to that, you can do:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <file>
```

This will keep the files on the repo with the last version before you --assume-unchanged the file.

Hope that helps,

Cheers